# How i can create Guests in another controller (for me it is Events)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restful-architecture

I am stuck on creating Guests in my Events controller.

An error from rails:

> undefined method `permit' for [{"name"=>"John"},
>   {"name"=>"Mike"}]:Array

How can I save Guests from Events controller, please help.

This is my EventsController:

class EventsController < ApplicationController

```
 def create
    @event = Event.create(event_params)
    @guest = Guest.create(guest_params)

    respond_with [@event, @guest]

  end

private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :description, :date)
  end

  def guest_params
    params.require(:guests).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

So, this is JSON from the view:

```
date:"25.07.2016"
description:"Biggest Show"
guests:[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mike"}]
name:"Night Show"
```

My class Event.rb:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guests
  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge(include: :guests))
  end
end
```

My class Guest.rb:

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  def as_json(options = {})
    super
  end
end
```

And Guest controller (if it more helpful):

```
class GuestsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def index
    respond_with Guest.all
  end

  def show
    respond_with Guest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    respond_with Guest.create(guest_params)
  end


  private
  def guest_params
    params.require(:guest).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `guests` in your view is an array of hashes `[{name: "John"}, {name: "Mike"}]`, you should do something like this in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @event = Event.create(event_params)
    @guests = guests_params[:guests].map { |guest|
      Guest.create(name: guest[:name], event: @event)
    }

    respond_with @event
  end

  private
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, :description, :date)
    end

    def guests_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:guests)
    end
end
```

Alternatively you could change your view to return `guests: { name_1: "John", name_2: "Mike", name_3: ... ]` and then use a `permit` method, that expects the index of the guest:

```
# app/controllers/events_controller.rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    @guests = (1..max_index).map { |index|
      Guest.create(guest_params(index).merge({ event: @event }))
    }
    ...
  end

  private
    ...
    def guest_params index
      params.require(:guests).permit("name_#{index}")
    end
end
```

I have not checked the code against the interpreter, but I think you get the idea :)

EDIT: changed `event_params.guests` to `params[:event][:guests]`, since guests is not a method or field of the `event_params` hash. Also removed guests from the `permit` method, because it could give an error when creating the event. But I am not sure if this is a good practice solution or if it even works exactly that way. It's still just to give the idea :)

Comment: I get the idea, but rails return me another error((:   `undefined method `guests' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fe0383ef7b8>` if I use your first method - `@guests = event_params.guests.map { |guest|
      Guest.create(name: guest.name, event: @event)
    }`

Comment: Could you provide the full error log with the lines the error is linked to? EDIT: I see. `guests` is not a method or field of `event_params` but it's a part of the hash. I'll change my original post.

Comment: undefined method `guests' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fe042400068>                                              def create
    @event = Event.create(event_params)
    @guests = event_params.guests.map { |guest|   #here is an error
      Guest.create(name: guest.name, event: @event)
    }

Comment: Request

Parameters:

{"name"=>"Biggest Show",
 "description"=>"Night Show",
 "date"=>"25-09-2016",
 "guests"=>[{"name"=>"Mike"},
 {"name"=>"Tim"}],
 "format"=>"json",
 "event"=>{"name"=>"Biggest Show",
 "description"=>"Night Show",
 "date"=>"25-09-2016"}}

Comment: Anyway rails returns an error: `undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass`        13  @guests = params[:event][:guests].map { |guest|   #here an error

Comment: Ok... try to add another params method for the `guests` parameter and use that one. I'm not sure right now why the hash is empty, but maybe this will fix it. I'll edit this in the original post.

Comment: I'd change my controller and guests creates now. Here is controller - `@guests = guests_params[:guests].map { |guest|
      Guest.create(name: guest[:name], event: @event)
    }
    respond_with [@event, @guests]                                                             def guests_params
    params.permit(guests: [:name])
  end` But ruby returns another error `undefined method `persisted?' for` in this line -       `  respond_with [@event, @guests]   `

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `respond_with` does, but it seems it calls `persisted?` on all given parameters. And since `@guests` is an array and not an active record element, it has no such method. If it should return the json-hash of the two elements you should probably consider using `render` with a json view file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'd delete @guests from respond_with and now no errors, guests and events creates.

Answer (score 0):

Change `guest_params` method to:

```
def guest_params
  params.permit(guests: [:name])
end
```

you can't call permit on an array